# React js image Resize not working before uploading to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage

i am trying to resize the picture on client side but getting error 'resize is not a function'.
All dependencies, are correct and cannot see issue with the code.
Would appreciate your view and pointing out the issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";
import { uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage } from "../firebase_handlers/firebaseStorageHandler";

const ImageFirestoreUplaoderComponent = () => {
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [resizedImages, setResizedImages] = useState([]);
  const [thumbnailImages, setThumbnailImages] = useState([]);
  const [processingComplete, setProcessingComplete] = useState(false);

  // Function to encode a file to base64
  const encodeToBase64 = (file) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };

      reader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

  // Function to encode an array of files to base64
  const encodeFilesToBase64 = async (files) => {
    try {
      const encodedImages = await Promise.all(
        files.map((file) => encodeToBase64(file))
      );
      return encodedImages;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error encoding files to base64:", error);
      return [];
    }
  };

  // Resizing and creating thumbnail miniature
  const resizeImages = async (base64Images) => {
    try {
      const resizedImages = [];
      const thumbnailImages = [];

      await Promise.all(
        base64Images.map(async (base64) => {
          try {
            // Resize image to a maximum width of 800px
            const resizedDataUrl = await Resizer.resize(base64, 800, 600);
            resizedImages.push({
              dataUrl: resizedDataUrl,
              file: null, // You can set the original file here if needed for later use
            });

            // Create a thumbnail miniature with a maximum width of 200px
            const thumbnailDataUrl = await Resizer.resize(base64, 200, 150);
            thumbnailImages.push({
              dataUrl: thumbnailDataUrl,
              file: null,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error resizing image:", error);
          }
        })
      );

      return { resizedImages, thumbnailImages };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error resizing images:", error);
      return { resizedImages: [], thumbnailImages: [] };
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resizedImages.length > 0 && processingComplete) {
      // Call the upload function only if resizedImages contains valid data
      handleUploadImages();
      // Reset states after clicking upload
      setSelectedFiles([]);
      setResizedImages([]);
      setThumbnailImages([]);
      setProcessingComplete(false);
    }
  }, [resizedImages, processingComplete]);

  const handleImageChange = async (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setSelectedFiles((prevSelectedFiles) => [...prevSelectedFiles, ...files]);
      resolve();
    });

    const processImages = async () => {
      const base64Images = await encodeFilesToBase64(selectedFiles);
      const { resizedImages, thumbnailImages } = await resizeImages(
        base64Images
      );
      setResizedImages(resizedImages);
      setThumbnailImages(thumbnailImages);
      setProcessingComplete(true);
    };

    if (selectedFiles.length > 0) {
      await processImages();
    }
  };

  const handleUploadImages = async () => {
    await uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage(resizedImages, thumbnailImages);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleImageChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUploadImages}>
        Upload Resized Images and Thumbnail Miniatures to Firebase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageFirestoreUplaoderComponent;
```

and firebase function to uplaod images as last step:

```
import { storage } from "../firebase_setup/firebase";
import { ref, uploadString } from "firebase/storage";

const storageRef = ref(storage, "some-child");

const uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage = async (
  resizedImages,
  thumbnailImages
) => {
  try {
    const allImages = [...resizedImages, ...thumbnailImages];

    const uploadPromises = allImages.map(async (imageData, index) => {
      const { dataUrl } = imageData;

      // Convert dataUrl to base64 format (remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," or similar prefix)
      const base64Data = dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");

      // Use uploadString to upload the base64 data to Firebase Storage
      const uploadTask = uploadString(storageRef, base64Data, "base64");
      console.log(imageData);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        uploadTask.then(
          (snapshot) => {
            console.log(`Image ${index + 1} uploaded successfully!`);
            resolve(snapshot);
          },
          (error) => reject(error)
        );
      });
    });
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);
    console.log("All images uploaded successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading images to Firebase Storage:", error);
  }
};

export { uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage };
```

Something is wrong with resizing and sure what is causing it.

Comment: Based on the npm module [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer), it looks like the function is named `imageFileResizer` and not `resize` like you have it. That should be why it's telling you 'resize is not a function'.

Comment: thanks, i must have left this as i was experimenting with various methods. But anyway, i see my 'resizeImage' function is not okay because it captures error when trying to browse for files for the second time which produces error ''Error resizing image: TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.''  - like there is some issue with async nature. i would need to have a closer look but perhaps you can see how to improve this?:)

Comment: i can see that resizeImages function returns 'nulls' - what would be the correct function? if you have any idea then appreciated!